# Packaging stub files

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, python-3.5

Let's say I have very simple package with a following structure:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

Content of the files:

- `setup.py`:

  ```
  from distutils.core import setup

  setup(
      name='foobar',
      version='',
      packages=['foo', 'foo.bar'],
      url='',
      license='Apache License 2.0',
      author='foobar',
      author_email='',
      description=''
  )
  ```
- `foo/bar/__init__.py`:

  ```
  def foobar(x):
      return x
  ```
- The remaining files are empty.

I install the package using `pip`:

```
cd foobar
pip install .
```

and can confirm it is installed correctly.

Now I want to create a separate package with stub files:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── __init__.pyi
│   └── __init__.pyi
└── setup.py
```

Content of the files:

- `setup.py`:

  ```
  from distutils.core import setup
  import sys
  import pathlib

  setup(
      name='foobar_annot',
      version='',
      packages=['foo', 'foo.bar'],
      url='',
      license='Apache License 2.0',
      author='foobar',
      author_email='',
      description='',
      data_files=[
          (
              'shared/typehints/python{}.{}/foo/bar'.format(*sys.version_info[:2]),
              ["foo/bar/__init__.pyi"]
          ),
      ],
  )
  ```
- `foo.bar.__init__.pyi`:

  ```
  def foobar(x: int) -> int: ...
  ```

I can install this package, see that it creates `anaconda3/shared/typehints/python3.5/foo/bar/__init__.pyi` in my Anaconda root, but it doesn't look like it is recognized by PyCharm (I get no warnings). When I place `pyi` file in the main package everything works OK.

I would be grateful for any hints how to make this work:

- I've been trying to make some sense from [PEP 484 - Storing and distributing stub files](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#storing-and-distributing-stub-files) but to no avail. Even `pathlib` part seem to offend my version of `distutils`
- PY-18597 and https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1190#issuecomment-188526651 seem to be related but somehow I cannot connect the dots.
- I tried putting stubs in the `.PyCharmX.X/config/python-skeletons` but it didn't help.'

Some things that work, but don't resolve the problem:

- Putting stub files in the current project and marking as sources.
- Adding stub package root to the interpreter path (at least in some simple cases).

So the questions: *How to create a minimal, distributable package with Python stubs, which will be recognized by existing tools*. Based on the experiments I suspect one of two problems:

- I misunderstood the structure which should be created by the package in the `shared/typehints/pythonX.Y` - if this is true, how should I define `data_files`?
- PyCharm doesn't consider these files at all (this seem to be contradicted by some comments in the linked issue).
- It suppose to work just fine, but I made some configure mistake and looking for external problem which doesn't exist.
- Are there any established procedures to troubleshoot problems like this?

Comment: Which PyCharm version and which OS?

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that you didn't include the `foo/__init__.pyi` file in your stub distribution. Even though it's empty, it makes `foo` a stub files package, and enables search for `foo.bar`.

You can modify the `data_files` in your `setup.py` to include both

```
data_files=[
    (
        'shared/typehints/python{}.{}/foo/bar'.format(*sys.version_info[:2]),
        ["foo/bar/__init__.pyi"]
    ),

    (
        'shared/typehints/python{}.{}/foo'.format(*sys.version_info[:2]),
        ["foo/__init__.pyi"]
    ),
],
```